# Failed to download repository information. Error?

Tags: software-center, repository

I am new here. I just installed Ubuntu and I am very happy. I tried to install a program from Ubuntu Software Center. It said "Available from "universe" source". So I clicked "Use this source". So, the download started. But I have a problem. Just after a bit, it gives an error. It says "Failed to download repository information. Check your Internet connection". I was very confused.

Here are the error details:

```
    W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please help? :(

I am trying to install 2 programs.

Answer (score 3):

First, try out these couple of commands from the terminal:

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
```

Open system settings (from terminal you may enter:)

```
gnome-control-center
```

Now click on **Software Sources** and under the **Ubuntu Software** tab, make sure every thing's checked and change the **Download from:** list control to **Main Server**.
 Now you may try out downloading your apps again. (This worked for me before! In some rare cases a restart might help too.)

Comment: No, the first 3 commands didn't work, and I couldn't find any Ubuntu Software tab, nor any Software Sources button. I only find a Software & Updates button.

Comment: Try by adding **sudo** infront of them, eg: **sudo apt-get autoclean**

Answer (score 1):

just open nano /etc/apt/sources.list

and replace all 'pk' to 'us'

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no connection to the Internet. This could happen for various reasons. One of the reasons could be that you are behind a proxy server. A guide for Ubuntu to configure the proxy settings for various tools (incl apt-get) can be found [on this website](http://www.phulstaert.be/?p=21).

I also noticed that the pk.archive.ubuntu.com is not complete. The en.archive.ubuntu.com includes files that could not be found on the pk mirror. You might consider trying to change to the en variant by editing the /etc/apt/sources.list file. You might want to consider to read up a bit about apt-get and the sources.list file before changing anything and always make a backup before changing anything.

Comment: OK. However, I have full Internet access on Ubuntu. And I never used a proxy on Ubuntu. This is a fresh install which I did just a few hours ago before making this thread. So I don't think it's a problem with the connection.

Comment: Hamza, have you already tried changing the mirror like i suggested in the second paragraph?
You can see for yourself that this specific mirror is incomplete:
browse to 
http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/ 
with a browser and compare it to 
http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/
You will see the difference.